# Validating Java objects field-by-field

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

I'm doing analyses on Java validation.

I need to build a module that validates an object [graph] field-by-field, using annotation and supporting custom domain-driven annotations. The most important aspect is that an *invalid* object **must not be rejected** (e.g. by underlying persistence layer) but instead marked as invalid.

For example, pick a class with a number of attributes. If any is invalid (e.g. missing or bad valued) I want to know which one is and mark it in another place as invalid. It is important that I get the name of **all** the fields that didn't pass validation, whether it's a primitive field or a child entity with a validation problem.

I have taken a look at `javax.validation` but I couldn't figure out the role of `ConstraintViolation`: it is returned by the validator when a validation error is found, **but** AFAIK doesn't show the field name to collect.

The question is: do you have any example of using any implementation of javax.validation that display the list of the **field names** that are found to be invalid for each validated bean?

Also, can I introduce custom attributes instead of adding a `ValidatedBy` attribute for each recurring attribute to be validated with custom logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the name of the element that caused the ConstraintViolation you must use

```
Path path =  ConstraintViolation.getPropertyPath();
// a path is an iterable of Path.Node objects
// the last node element in the path is the element that caused the violation
// You can get it's name via
Path.Node node = ...;
node.getName();
```

Take a look at the [JSR-303 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) chapter 4.2 for details on the Path.